# Flutter onTap for inkwell

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently working on a page where I have bunch of containers in the page and they should be able change colors from 'bluegrey' to 'grey' when tapped.

The output that I have right now is :[image]

The output that I want is :[image]

My code for this is:`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Hexcolor('#e9f1fe'),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, right: 16.0, left: 16.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Random Text 1',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 26.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, right: 16.0, left: 16.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Random Text 2',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 26.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, right: 16.0, left: 16.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Random Text 3',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 26.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

`

Can I get some help with this? A code snippet would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I would like to answer.

You can do something like.

```
Map<String, Color> buttonColors = { };
```

Make an InkWell widget like this,

```
 InkWell(
    onTap: () => {
      setState(() {
        buttonColors ['button1'] = Colors.blueGrey;
      })
    },
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, right: 16.0, left: 16.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        color: buttonColors ['button1'] ?? Colors.grey,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Random Text 1',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

If they click on your button, set the state for `'button1'` in the `buttonColors` map.
When it is rendering your button, it will check whether the value is `null` for `button1`, if it is so, it will apply `Colors.grey`, else if you have clicked and set the state, then it has some color value and it displays that color. Here `Colors.blueGrey`.

Comment: It works but the color doesn't revert back to original color when I don't tap.

Comment: Then you have check whether the color is already being set and then you have to set the state. Something like this.
`if(buttonColor['button1'] != null) { make it blue color } else { make it null } `